# ALERT: Transaction Error. Exception thrown in contract code.(metamask)

Tags: solidity, metamask

i am working on truffle Pet-shop with react, i am using local blockchain ganache with metamask, The issue I'm encountering with my application is that when i am trying to call **deleteAdopter** function from UI, metamask opens and says

> ALERT: Transaction Error. Exception thrown in contract code.

but if i call **adopt** function it executes successfully on contract and my UI changes and pet mark as adopted.

it is working in remix, where i can call deleteAdopter function,it executes successfully and on calling getAdopters function it returns updated array of addressess
here is the code **Adoption.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Adoption {
    address[16] public adopters;

    // Adopting a pet
    function adopt(uint petId) public returns (uint) {
        require(petId >= 0 && petId <= 15);
        require(adopters[petId] == address(0), "already adopted pet");
        adopters[petId] = msg.sender;

        return petId;
    }

    // Retrieving the adopters
    function getAdopters() public view returns (address[16] memory) {
        return adopters;
    }
    
    //Releasing a pet 
    function deleteAdopter(uint petId) public returns(uint) {
        require(msg.sender == adopters[petId], "Only adopters can call this function");
        delete adopters[petId];
        return petId;
    }
}


// Releasing a pet
//  function release(uint petId) public returns (uint) {
//    require(petId >= 0 && petId <= 15);

//    if (adopters[petId] == msg.sender) {
//      adopters[petId] = address(0);
//    }

//    return petId;
//  }
```

[image]

Comment: It probably fails on the validation that `require(msg.sender == adopters[petId]`. Can you check that the "Account 3" (sender) address is really saved in `adopters[petId]`?

Comment: yes, i have checked everything carefully